# What is causing curling and white, hairy growth on the leaves of my chili plants?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, chili

The leaves on my chili plants have started curling up, and on the underside of the leaves along the petiole, I've noticed a line of very fine white hairs. What's wrong with my plant?

Comment: Photos are really important in scenarios like this.

Comment: Hi Paul! As @VianEsterhuizen said, we really need some pictures in order to diagnose your problem, including the whole plant, the damaged leaves and the part that looks like white hair. Also, where do you live? Are your plants indoors or out? What type of soil? If you look at some of our other questions about [tag:chili] plants, you might find something similar that has helpful answers. Welcome to the site!